# Google Chrome crash the whole system on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, crash, gpu, amd-radeon

I have been using Google Chrome with Hardware acceleration with no problem and very good results on my Xubuntu 14.04 Dell Latitude E6440 with Radeon GPU. Lately, (probably due to some "System Update" that I do regularly as recommended by Ubuntu) Google-Chrome have stopped working. I start it. I get the browser and after 5 seconds the whole system crashes !!! and I need to re-login.

How can I make google-chrome to work again ? (safe mode, no GPU ?)

How can I make it work with hardware acceleration as before ?

Here is what I got on the google-chrome stderr:

```
xxx@dellorian:~$ cat c.log 
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[11245:11256:0726/214546:ERROR:gpu_watchdog_thread.cc(253)] The GPU process hung. Terminating after 10000 ms.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[9:20:0727/004546:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(146)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandBuffer failed.
[9:20:0727/004546:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(405)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
[11317:11317:0726/214547:ERROR:x11_util.cc(81)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
[11211:11211:0727/004547:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(56)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
[11211:11211:0727/004547:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(524)] Failed to send GetTerminationStatus message to zygote
[11211:11211:0727/004547:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(524)] Failed to send GetTerminationStatus message to zygote
[11211:11241:0727/004547:ERROR:raw_channel_posix.cc(139)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
[11211:11241:0727/004547:ERROR:channel.cc(297)] RawChannel fatal error (type 1)
[11211:11241:0727/004547:ERROR:raw_channel_posix.cc(139)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
[11211:11241:0727/004547:ERROR:channel.cc(297)] RawChannel fatal error (type 1)
```

Here is my dmesg:

```
[11589.851137] Watchdog[11256]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fdfe09d1dde sp 00007fdfcfdb8670 error 6 in chrome[7fdfdcaab000+51d2000]
[11591.998375] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:c01 = 261ad03/e
[11591.998382] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
[11592.003911] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x0000000000242000).
[11592.004069] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[11592.004073] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800367bec00
[11592.004075] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800367bec04
[11592.004077] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800367bec08
[11592.004078] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800367bec0c
[11592.004079] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800367bec10
[11592.145528] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 2 usecs
[11592.145532] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[11592.145534] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[11592.145593] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 2 usecs
[11592.145599] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 1 usecs
[11592.147085] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[11592.147129] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[11592.147172] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[11592.147199] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[11592.147235] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
xxx@dellorian:~$
```